# Remove last 2 lines of 'ls' output

Tags: bash

I want to delete some revisions of docker images. I want to delete the last 2 lines. I'm able to print the last 2 lines with:

```
ls -lt | tail -n 2
```

gives my the 2 last lines.

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov  9 10:56 541a303d3c82785293f89a401038ac33ef2b54b6aeb09efd3d3bda7xxxx
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Oct 25 12:07 c74e1399c99de0c23517abc95bc9b16d09df5c4d518776e77d9ae67xxxx
```

Now is my question. How do I have to delete them?

I tried `ls -lt | tail -n 2 | rm -r *` but than I deleted everything (the whole output of `ls`)

Comment: `ls -t | tail -n 2 | xargs rm -r`  You may want to try with `xargs echo rm` first to make sure it's going to do what you want.

Comment: Generally, it is not a good idea to parse `ls` for things like this.  A better alternative would be using `find -exec`.

Comment: The `rm -r *` in your faulty command ignored its standard input — `rm` doesn't read from standard input unless you use the `-i` option.  The shell expanded `*` into all the file and directory names in the current directory that don't start with a `.` and passed those names as arguments to `rm`, which then did what it is supposed to — remove the file names it is provided as arguments.

Comment: @Questionmark Okay didn't know. Can you maybe give an example on how you can use it in my case?

Comment: Would a "delete everything from x long ago" work in your case?  That would probably be the cleanest way...

Comment: Going the ls route, I would probably do something like `rm -rf $(ls -t | tail -n2)`.

Comment: Thanks, those hints will help me to find the right command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get that to work.  I would probably use something like `rm -rf $(ls -t | tail -n2)`, but [parsing `ls` is really not recommended](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

A cleaner way to do this would be to use `find`.  You can use that to delete everything before a certain time.  Something like this: `find . -mtime -180 -exec rm -f {} \;` would delete everything newer than 180 days ago.

I would highly recommend testing whatever you are planning to run before you actually do the delete!

Comment: Even better. Thank you about the info about parsing `ls`. Didn't know that actually.

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea; however, whatever comes after 'rm' gets deleted, which is why * deleted all instead of what you were trying to pipe into it.

This is a pretty clean way to do it though

```
    rm `ls | tail -n 2`
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for test :

```
 ls -t | tail -n 2 | xargs -i -t echo {}
```

> -t, --verbose
>          Print the command line on the standard error output before executing it.

After the test, you can delete them with :

```
ls -t | tail -n 2 | xargs -i -t rm -fr {}

rm -fr 541a303d3c82785293f89a401038ac33ef2b54b6aeb09efd3d3bda7xxxx 
rm -fr c74e1399c99de0c23517abc95bc9b16d09df5c4d518776e77d9ae67xxxx
```